# How to achieve this relay control functionality in an alternative way?

Tags: relay

To clarify the question I draw the following illustration:

[image]

Inside an enclosure I basically need a control such that when the SW switch above is closed, the mains relay latches if the momentary push button PB is pressed and released. And the mains relay stays latched unless the SW is opened.

Both relays above are normally open non-latching type. And as you see, I use a DC relay to achieve this. If SW is closed and PB is pressed and released, both relays will stay activated since the output of the DC relay is fed back to both relay trigger inputs. So after PB is released the Bulb will remain ON and can be turned off only by opening the SW.

So the operation required is:

SW is closed & PB is pressed and released --> Bulb is ON (unless SW is opened again)

SW is open --> Bulb is always OFF

My questions are:

1-) Is there a type of relay where one can achieve this operation with a single relay?

2-) What IC gate type would replace the Relay_DC?

Answer (score 1):

A single DPDT relay should do.

However, two relays may be used for greater isolation between the low voltage and high voltage contacts.

Here's the schematic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need what is known as a start-stop circuit (or run-stop circuit): -

[image]

Image from [here](https://drstienecker.com/tech-332/5-ladder-logic/). The above uses a 24 volt DC relay but, it's the same circuit when used with an AC power line.

To control your load, choose a relay with an extra contact to those shown above. Here's a version that uses one contact to do latching and output switching: -

[image]

Taken and modified from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/247704/will-this-ac-ac-ssr-work-for-a-safety-start-stop-switch-for-a-power-tool).

> *What IC gate type would replace the Relay_DC?*

You would probably use a flip-flop. Maybe a D flip-flop type that has a clear input so, once the flip-flop latches it can be unlatched by the clear (or reset) line.

Comment: In my case the control side should be low voltage because it will be exposed to an interlock where a person might touch. The only part AC should be the relay contact for the load.

Comment: @ty_1917 then what would you change on the circuit diagram to get that isolation? a small change only.

Comment: @ty_1917 imagine the top circuit used a 5 volt relay instead and, an extra contact was brought out for the load (as mentioned). Clearly, you need to have contact-contact isolation ratings in accordance with your safety requirements.

Comment: @Andyaka " a relay with an extra contact " Is there any jargon to search/google such relay like SPDT ect?

Comment: I'd call it a DPDT relay (dual pole dual throw) or dual pole single throw (DPST). DPDT has normally open and normally closed contacts. DPST has normally open contacts @ty_1917

Comment: @Andyaka I see I found 5V coil DPST here https://docs.rs-online.com/7dcf/0900766b80b0bc3f.pdf And I can now use single relay for the purpose with correct wiring. But one last question about the thing you mentioned. What can we say about contact-contact isolation for this omron case?

Comment: This is what the DS says: *Clearance and creepage distance between coil and contacts: 8 mm/8 mm. Between contacts of the same polarity: 3 mm/4 mm* <-- in my opinion, you should look for 8 mm in both scenarios @ty_1917 <-- 3mm/4mm isn't enough for safety standards between contacts and other contacts.

Comment: @Andyaka Hmm maybe I should stick with two relay as in my question. Or go for the flip flop..

Comment: I'd go the flip-flop route personally. Finding a relay with contact-contact 8mm clearance is going to reduce the options for you big time.

Comment: +1 from me. I note also a -1. Not obvuious why - but there has been a lot of hard to understand downvoting of late :-)

Comment: Thanks for investigating @RussellMcMahon