# Mains safety shutoff

Tags: mains, safety, switching, contactor

I have a problem. I have a sensor in a piece of equipment that needs to switch off that equipment if it detects a dangerous gas. The equipment must remain off until a manual reset is applied. What kind of switch/contactor does that? Is there a special name for it? It should be inherently failsafe.

Comment: How about a relay that interrupts power to its own coil when de-energized? Once it's off, it can't come back on.

Comment: When a relay's contact controls it's own coil (latching action) I've heard this called a ["seal-in" circuit](https://instrumentationtools.com/what-is-seal-in-circuit/).

Answer (score 0):

"Failsafe" has a variety of meanings in different industries. Presumably the sensor output in this case is configured so that the output "on" verifies that dangerous gas is **not** detected.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiOSpq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Manual reset. Auto-off if OUT signal or sensor power is lost.*

Depending on the risk category you may need to employ redundant circuits. Industrial machinery uses dual channel redundancy and I have explained some of the principles of operation in the posts linked below:

- [Self Checking Circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/244088/73158).
- [Symbol or marking on safety relay](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/240280/symbol-or-marking-on-safety-relay/240352#240352).

Comment: Just a warning: If your dangerous gas is flammable or explosive, this approach will certainly increase the safety.  But, the approach in itself won't be certifiable for operation in a hazardous area unless the design of the switch, the equipment and the sensor all meet other requirements.